# Swift NSArray mutation

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have two variables one is mutable array second one is immutable.

```
let mutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: ["1","2","3"])

let immutableArray: NSArray = mutableArray
```

But when I do append of the element to `mutableArray` my `immutableArray` is also changing.

So my assumptions is to use `.copy` in `immutableArray` assigning. But is it optimal varian for solving of the issue?

Comment: The assignment you do in 

    `let immutableArray: NSArray = mutableArray`
doesn't make a deep copy. 

Your assumption is correct, for that you will need to make `.copy`.

Comment: @ShamasS but if arrays are quite large using of the .copy will or will not do impact on the performance ?

Comment: If they are fairly large, `copy` would definitely be expensive.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use a Swift `Array`?

Comment: @MartinR there is strong dependency on the usage of the Obj-c data structures. By strong I mean all sub projects are using them in classes and as parameters in functions.

Comment: `Array` and `NSArray` bridge seamlessly. But if you need the *reference* semantics of NSArray then that's how it is: you need to make a copy to get an independent array. Note that the copy is "shallow", not deep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Swift foundation type `Array` instead, they are immutable by default and value types instead of references types.

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3] // type is: [Int]
let strings = numbers.map { $0.description } // type is: [String]
print(strings) // ["1", "2", "3"]

// THIS DOES NOT COMPILE
strings.append("foo") //Compilation error: cannot use mutating member on immultable value `strings` is a `let` constant

// Instead, super easily, declare a mutable copy just by this line
var mutableStrings = strings // since `Array` is value type, this only copies values over
mutableStrings.append("foo")
print(mutableStrings) // ["1", "2", "3", "foo"]
```

**Or do you need NSArray for some particular reason?**

Using `Array` has many advantages, use can use `map` (as done above), `reduce`, `flatMap`, `filter` etc directly. If you want to use `map` on an `NSArray` you need to cast to `AnyObject` and then filter out optionals using `flatMap`:

```
let numbers = NSArray(array: [1, 2, 3])
let strings = numbers.map { ($0 as AnyObject).description  }.flatMap { $0 }
print(strings) // ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Which is just ugly and messy... So why not use `Array` right away instead? :)

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in this way

```
let mutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: ["1","2","3"])
let immutableArray: NSArray = NSArray(array: mutableArray)

mutableArray.add("4")
print(mutableArray) // (1,2,3,4)
print(immutableArray) // (1,2,3)
```